Combining unstructured Tables from multiple Macro-enabled excel files
I have different survey responses in a macro-enabled excel file, they are password protected and idk the pw. There are 6 tables on the same sheets in each response, like this:

I would like to combine all the files in to 6 sheets and having one table on each sheet. In each table, all the responses should be included (while the text like “Completion instructions/ please add more rows, etc" will not be included.) Even the response is blank for No.1-5, I would like to still keep it in the combined file.
How can I do it through queries? Different tables were included in the same column and  I wonder how I can break them into different sheets

Use Power Query - one query per sheet.
See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For starters, try steps 1 through 5 of "Handling Multiple Excel Files and Multiple Sheets in Power Query" (Kyle Gibson, medium.com). Then add a ResponseId column. Call the query "Responses Raw".
Then, create another query called "Survey Responses" that starts with "Responses Raw" and converts that into a table, one row per file, of everything you want to see once per survey response (like name, etc). Make sure you keep that unique identifier column.
Create another query called Table1 (or whatever) where you start from "Responses Raw", adds a column called "Table" that contains Table 1 (plus a c of each response, adds unique id that identifies the corresponding row in the "Survey Responses" query, and then, assuming your last step is called #"Added Column", append a step called CombinedSubtables that has code of fCombineSubtables(#"Added Column")
fCombineSubtables doesn't exist, you have to create it, with code like
(Source as table) => 
let
  Tables = Table.ConvertRows(
    Source,
    each Table.AddColumn(
      [Table],
      "ResponseId",
      [ResponseId],
      Int64.Type
    )
  ),
  Combined = Table.Combine(Tables),
  Reordered = Table.ReorderColumns(
    Combined,
    {"ResponseId”} & List.RemoveItems(
      Table.ColumnNames(Combined),
      {"ResponseId”}
    )
  )
as
  Reordered

If that works, then create another for Table2, etc, etc.
